# Не могу написать скрипт для импорта CSV файлов в таблицы БД

Tags: django, csv, импорт

[Делал по статье](https://adityakedawat.medium.com/importing-csv-file-into-django-models-using-django-management-command-716eda305e61)

1.создание проекта - было

2.создание приложение - было

3.создание модели - было

*далее взял в работу только модель "категории" (для теста скрипта)

+Создал admin.py в приложении reviews

+Провел миграции и создал Суперюзера

4.В приложении reviews создал папку management/commands и в нее положил файл со скриптом load_category_data.py

5.Перенес(скопировал) файл category.csv в директорию с  manage.py

Запускаю команду python manage.py load_category_data

*Пишет что не знает такой команды
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Буду премного благодарен если кто подскажет что я сделал не так?**

```
#load_category_data
from csv import DictReader
from django.core.management import BaseCommand

# Import the model
from reviews.models import Category


ALREDY_LOADED_ERROR_MESSAGE = """
If you need to reload the child data from the CSV file,
first delete the db.sqlite3 file to destroy the database.
Then, run `python manage.py migrate` for a new empty
database with tables"""


class Command(BaseCommand):
    # Show this when the user types help
    help = "Loads data from category.csv"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # Show this if the data already exist in the database
        if Category.objects.exists():
            print('Category data already loaded...exiting.')
            print(ALREDY_LOADED_ERROR_MESSAGE)
            return
        # Show this before loading the data into the database
        print("Loading Categorys data")

        # Code to load the data into database
        for row in DictReader(open('./category.csv')):
            category = Category(id=row['id'], name=row['name'],
                                slug=row['slug'])

            category.save()
```

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    """Модель Категорий"""

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        verbose_name="Название категории",
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(
        max_length=50,
        unique=True,
        verbose_name="поле слаг_Категория",
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug
```

```
#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from reviews.models import Category

@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['id','name','slug']
```

Comment: Первое "не так" - не поместили тут текст кода, а только скан. Текст размещайте, чтобы шансы на ответ повысить.

Comment: @Сергей
Спасибо за совет
Добавил код

Comment: Название папки должно быть `management/commands/`, а не `managment/commands/`, после исправления джанга должна увидить команду)

Comment: Спасибо @floydya
Там еще куча ошибок